# getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: java, tomcat

Criei duas páginas de erros iguais para dois sistemas que funcionam dentro do mesmo Tomcat.
Uma das páginas funcionam normalmente e a outra ocorre o erro a seguir. 
Dentro do ambiente de desenvolvimento e homologação o erro não acontece. A versão do Tomcat de todos os ambientes é a mesma: 7.0.52

```
Grave: Exception Processing ErrorPage[exceptionType=java.lang.Exception, location=/template/dispatch-error.jsp] org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:585)at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:465)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:460)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:411)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:200)
at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:636)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:213)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:104)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:186)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:126)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:80)
at org.apache.jsp.template.dispatch_002derror_jsp._jspService(dispatch_002derror_jsp.java:236)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
```

Página JSP :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java" %> <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> <%@ page isErrorPage="true" import="java.io.*"%><div class="container">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${pageContext.errorData.statusCode == '404' || pageContext.errorData.statusCode == '400' ||
                                    pageContext.errorData.statusCode == '0' }">
            <span class="laranja">
                <h1>A Página ou arquivo solicitado não foi encontrado, clique no botão Voltar do seu navegador<br/>
            </span>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <span class="laranja">
                <h1>Ocorreu um erro. Clique no botão voltar do seu navegador</h1>
                <br/>
            </span>
                <c:if test="${pageContext.errorData.statusCode == '500'}">
                    <div id="central">
                        <span id="mensagem" style="display: none;"></span>
                        <span id="error" style="display:none;">
                                <%=exception.getMessage()%>
                                <%
                                    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                                    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
                                    exception.printStackTrace(printWriter);
                                    out.println(stringWriter);
                                    printWriter.close();
                                    stringWriter.close();
                                %>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </c:if>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que o problema está na quebra de linha entre as tags JSP. Ao interpretar o código JSP, alguns servidores de aplicação tentam escrever a quebra de linha entre as duas tags, o que resulta no erro. O link abaixo contém uma discussão antiga sobre o assunto.

http://www.guj.com.br/java/19660-javalangillegalstateexception-getoutputstream-has-already-been-called-for-this-response